# How can I loop the script 1000 times to get the data in different cells and get URL value from different cells?

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

How can I loop the script 1000 times to get the data in different cells and get URL value from different cells?

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    
    Dim ie As InternetExplorer
    Dim ht As HTMLDocument
    
    Set ie = New InternetExplorer
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.navigate Workbooks("FINAL-1").Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A2").Value
    
    Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Loop
    
    Set ht = ie.document
    
    Workbooks("FINAL-1").Worksheets("sheet1").Range("C").Value = ht.getElementById("addr1").Value
    'Workbooks("FINAL-1").Worksheets("sheet1").Range("C2").Value = ht.getElementById("fullName").Value
    'Workbooks("FINAL-1").Worksheets("sheet1").Range("d2").Value = ht.getElementById("addr1").Value
    Workbooks("FINAL-1").Worksheets("sheet1").Range("D").Value = ht.getElementById("dob").Value
    Workbooks("FINAL-1").Worksheets("sheet1").Range("E").Value = ht.getElementById("applyDte").Value
    Workbooks("FINAL-1").Worksheets("sheet1").Range("B").Value = ht.getElementById("idNo").Value
    'Workbooks("FINAL-1").Worksheets("sheet1").Range("G2").Value = ht.getElementById("genderMtdtId").Value
    
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    
End Sub
```

Comment: `ie.navigate (range("a1").value)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Set ie = New InternetExplorer

ie.Visible = True



ie.navigate Workbooks("FINAL-1").Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A2").Value



Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    
Loop
```